# Boost::polymorphic_downcast Error with example

Tags: c++, boost

yesterday i was start reading boost documentation, i was copied example code, and program was returned error, whats wrong?

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/cast.hpp>


using namespace std;

class Fruit { public: virtual ~Fruit(){}; };
class Banana : public Fruit { };

int main()
{
    Fruit * fruit = new Fruit();
    Banana * banana = boost::polymorphic_downcast<Banana*>(fruit);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Assertion failed: dynamic_cast<target>(x) = x, file [...] boost\cast.hpp line 97
```

[Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm#Polymorphic_cast)

Comment: You missed the comment. *// ... logic which leads us to believe it is a Banana*. `new Fruit()` is definitely not a `Banana`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't just copy the example code. You replaced the comment that said:

```
// ... logic which leads us to believe it is a Banana
```

with something that doesn't lead us to believe that:

```
Fruit * fruit = new Fruit();
```

The assertion is expected, from the documentation you link to:

```
template <class Derived, class Base>
inline Derived polymorphic_downcast(Base* x);
// Effects: assert( dynamic_cast<Derived>(x) == x );
// Returns: static_cast<Derived>(x)
```

and fails because `fruit` does not point to an object with dynamic type `Banana`.

If you were to replace that line with something that does create a Banana:

```
Fruit * fruit = new Banana;
```

then the assertion (and the cast) should succeed, giving a correctly typed pointer to that Banana.